# Detecting mouse hover over a popover from openlayers3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, openlayers-3, onhover

I would like to detect when the mouse is hovering over a (bootstrap) popover from an openlayers3 map, so that I can leave the popover open in this case, but destroy it in all other cases.  My map has a lot of features with popovers containing links, so the user should be able to move the mouse to a link and click with the popover still open.  Putting a timer on the destroy event is really messy with all the different features with popovers I am displaying.  I'm not sure if the best solution is to attempt to detect the event via openlayers (is this possible?) or via bootstrap.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animik/fxp2pke1/5/) demonstrating the problem.

What is the best way to keep a popover open only when the mouse is over the popover?

Thanks for your help.

```
// define map
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 1,
        center: ol.proj.transform([0,0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
    })
});

// define popup overlay
popup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById("popup")
});
map.addOverlay(popup);

// define feature
var FeatureLayer = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
    map: map,
    features:  [new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Circle([0,0], 1000000),
    })]
})

// define mouse move event
$(map.getViewport()).on("mousemove", function(evt) {
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    var coordinate = map.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixel)
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel, coordinate);
});

// popover display function
var feature_prev
function displayFeatureInfo(pixel, coordinate) 
{
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });
    if (feature == feature_prev)  // if same feature, leave popup open
    {
        return
    }

    // if (mouse hovering over open popover)  <--------------------- how to detect this?
    //{
    //    return
    //}

    // display popover
    var element = popup.getElement();
    if (feature)  // if mouse is over feature
    {
        coords = ol.proj.transform([0,0], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
        popup.setPosition(coords);
        $(element).popover("destroy")
        $(element).popover({
            "html": true,
            "content":  "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link 1</a><br>"+
                        "<a href='http://openlayers.org'>Link 2</a>"
        });
        $(element).popover("show");
        feature_prev = feature
    }
    else
    {
        $(element).popover("destroy")
        feature_prev = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, the popover have `class` name `popover-content`, you can check if the mouse event's target is popup and then `return` to keep the popover open.

With this approach, the popover will close when you hover on your link in the popover. So, we have to ass extra condition to check for `a` tag too to keep it open when you are hovering on popup links.

```
if (e.target.className == 'popover-content' || e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    return;
}
```

Here is your working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxp2pke1/7/)**